# ELD Event Data Check Calculation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, binary, hex

Helloworld,

We create an ELD app and I must perform Event Data Check Calculation in Javascript.

See
http://eld-federal-requirements.readthedocs.io/en/latest/4-functional_requirements.html#event-data-check-calculation

I already sum all characters match in table 3 <#Table-3>. But I'm not sure how to calculate the data-check.

I make this for now:

```
[...]

//4.4.5.1.2 Event Data Check Calculation
    console.log(sumChars); // "722"
    var binary = sumChars.toString(2);
    //Output 8-bit byte, after operation is done.
    binary = ("000000000" + binary.toString(2)).substr(-8);

    //1. Three consecutive circular shift left (rotate no carry -left) operations; and
    binary = binary << 3;
    //Output 8-bit byte, after operation is done.
    binary = ("000000000" + binary.toString(2)).substr(-8);

    //2. A bitwise exclusive OR (XOR) operation with the hexadecimal value C3 (decimal 195; binary 11000011).
    binary = binary ^ 11000011;
    //Output 8-bit byte, after operation is done.
    binary = ("000000000" + binary.toString(2)).substr(-8);

    //The event data check value must be the hexadecimal representation of the output 8-bit byte.
    console.log(parseInt(binary, 2).toString(16).toUpperCase()); // "1B"
```

Did my calculation is good or not? My client tell me this is not good, but I don't understand the federal law calculation.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

Here is my sumChars calculation. Possibly wrong too.

```
var mapping = {"1":1,"2":2,"3":3,"4":4,"5":5,"6":6,"7":7,"8":8,"9":9,
    "A":17,"B":18,"C":19,"D":20,"E":21,"F":22,"G":23,"H":24,"I":25,"J":26,"K":27,"L":28,"M":29,"N":30,"O":31,"P":32,"Q":33,"R":34,"S":35,"T":36,"U":37,"V":38,"W":39,"X":40,"Y":41,"Z":42,
    "a":49,"b":50,"c":51,"d":52,"e":53,"f":54,"g":55,"h":56,"i":57,"j":58,"k":59,"l":60,"m":61,"n":62,"o":63,"p":64,"q":65,"r":66,"s":67,"t":68,"u":69,"v":70,"w":71,"x":72,"y":73,"z":74};
    //For all attributes, sum all caracters of all attributes with mapping table.
    var sumChars = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < eventRecord.eventType.toString().length; i++) {
        if(mapping[eventRecord.eventType.toString().charAt(i)]) {
            sumChars += mapping[eventRecord.eventType.toString().charAt(i)];
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < eventRecord.eventCode.toString().length; i++) {
        if(mapping[eventRecord.eventCode.toString().charAt(i)]) {
            sumChars += mapping[eventRecord.eventCode.toString().charAt(i)];
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < eventRecord.date.toString().length; i++) {
        if(mapping[eventRecord.date.toString().charAt(i)]) {
            sumChars += mapping[eventRecord.date.toString().charAt(i)];
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < eventRecord.time.toString().length; i++) {
        if(mapping[eventRecord.time.toString().charAt(i)]) {
            sumChars += mapping[eventRecord.time.toString().charAt(i)];
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < eventRecord.vehicleMiles.toString().length; i++) {
        if(mapping[eventRecord.vehicleMiles.toString().charAt(i)]) {
            sumChars += mapping[eventRecord.vehicleMiles.toString().charAt(i)];
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < eventRecord.totalEngineHours.toString().length; i++) {
        if(mapping[eventRecord.totalEngineHours.toString().charAt(i)]) {
            sumChars += mapping[eventRecord.totalEngineHours.toString().charAt(i)];
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < eventRecord.latitude.toString().length; i++) {
        if(mapping[eventRecord.latitude.toString().charAt(i)]) {
            sumChars += mapping[eventRecord.latitude.toString().charAt(i)];
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < eventRecord.longitude.toString().length; i++) {
        if(mapping[eventRecord.longitude.toString().charAt(i)]) {
            sumChars += mapping[eventRecord.longitude.toString().charAt(i)];
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < eventRecord.cmvVin.length; i++) {
        if(mapping[eventRecord.cmvVin.charAt(i)]) {
            sumChars += mapping[eventRecord.cmvVin.charAt(i)];
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < eventRecord.usernameId.length; i++) {
        if(mapping[eventRecord.usernameId.charAt(i)]) {
            sumChars += mapping[eventRecord.usernameId.charAt(i)];
        }
    }
```

Comment: `binary = ("000000000" + binary.toString(2)).substr(-8);` why are you working with strings here?? That makes no sense and will invalidate your calculations

Comment: Ok... What is your solution? How can be sure my binary is always 8 bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript isn't good for bit-wise operations. I think you have problem here in

```
//1. Three consecutive circular shift left (rotate no carry -left) operations; and
    binary = binary << 3;
```

First convert decimal to binary string as 8 bit binary, like 00100100  and shift left most 3 bit at the end of number, like 001 00100 = 00100001. Now you can convert back string into decimal number.
If you use more then one bytes then result is equal to 00100100000 and that is wrong.

Comment: Yup! You are right! Actually, I lost my job for this customer since Covid19, but I will follow your reply to the guy who replaced me. Thanks again, even after 4 years I shout this question.

Comment: Sorry to hear your loss but i know this isn't easy task. Mostly programming language is not good for custom data formats.